# Why Microsoft Ajax Minifier doesn't generate mini file with Team build 2010?

Tags: ajax, tfsbuild, microsoft-ajax-minifier

I just used the wonderful tool Microsoft Ajax Minifier and it's working very well when I build my MVC application on my machine but when I check-in in source control and started build by the Team Build 2010 it doesn't create the min files, for sure I can't put the mini files inside the source control as the recommendation from the Microsoft Ajax Minifier because it's like the dll it's generated every time you build your application so no need to put it in source control beside it can't be because you  will need always to check-out this file to build and this will prevent other from build using the team build, so what I need to do to make generate the mini file with team build 2010????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure it out, it becasue the paths, I create a post on my blog with images that describe why this problem happen and how to fix it and anyone need to see it just visit the following links

http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/use-microsoft-ajax-minifier-with-team-build/

Thanks

I hope it could help anyone else may face my problem.